# Case-sensitive duplicates removal string values in a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a collection "article_titles"

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("637c597f9a70ce15b7a2ffbe"),
        "title" : "Under pressure: when refugees feel pressured to leave their host countries",
        "authorId" : "abraith",
        "year" : 2022
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("637c597f9a70ce15b7a2ffbf"),
        "title" : "Under pressure: When Refugees Feel Pressured to Leave their Host Countries",
        "authorId" : "abraith",
        "year" : 2022
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("637c597f9a70ce15b7a2ffc0"),
        "title" : "Moving the Goalposts? Mutual Fund Benchmark Changes and Performance Manipulation",
        "authorId" : "rossi2",
        "year" : 2022
}
```

The first two for same authorId have same articles but case_sensitive. I want to remove the these same articles in the collection, one has upper case with all letters, others are not.

I was thinking to make lowercase all titles and aggregate them, but when I make it back the first letter uppercase, that is not true for all titles. For example

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("637c597f9a70ce15b7a2ffd2"),
        "title" : "Hiking during the COVID-19 pandemic: Demographic and visitor group factors associated with public health compliance",
        "authorId" : "brandon",
        "year" : 2022
}
```

here COVID-19 is all capital, in that case it will make these letters small case too. I want to keep one in these case-sensitive duplicate items.

I tried the following query, later I am lost what to do.

```
db.article_titles.aggregate([{$group:{"_id":{title:{$toLower:"$title"},authorId:"$authorId",year:"$year"}}},{$project:{_id:0, title:"$_id.title",year: "$_id.year",authorId:"$_id.authorId"}},{$out:"tmp"}])
```

Comment: Not so sure whether is this what you want. From what I understand your question, you want to group and remain existing title value.  [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3VlTd4fzOAn)

Comment: You need to define some rule for how to (programmatically) pick which `title` to keep. For example, do you want the one that has the most uppercase letters in it?

Comment: Yes, I want it to be consistent for all titles, if it is upper case for one I choose, it has to be upper case for all the rest of authors titles too. For which ```$first``` will not always be right